# Docker Container HttpUrlConnection Timeout Exception

Tags: java, docker, timeout, containers, httpurlconnection

I have an issue that is best explained in the image below. The lines in red are not working and it doesn't make sense. All the blue lines are successful. MyApp is a Java app that works in standalone mode to the docker ports to KsqlDB containers. Both MyApp Docker containers have this problem. I have rebuilt images, restarted host, checked pinging, you name I have tried it. Docker Host machine is Ubuntu.

If you have any idea what I can try please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out but in my defense the ports were open and I could hit them from other apps no problem. but what fixed it was Ubuntu's ufw. If you can please explain why this was the fix I would greatly appreciate it, as I thought it should have worked even without me adding to the firewall. Anyways hopefully it will help someone else out.

All I had to do was on HOST:

- ufw status

  ufw allow 8085

  ufw allow 8086

  ufw allow 8087

and magically it worked.